# Return all nodes and relationships from a matched node Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, return, cypher

I am looking to retrieve all nodes an relationships with respect to outgoing relationships only. That is all nodes 'b' that are connected to 'a' in this manner:

```
(a)-->(b)
```

In my situation. I have User nodes that are then connected to another node, lets label it 'work'. And from work node we relate out to many other nodes that may be labeled 'work_friends' or 'work_locations'. This User node may also have other nodes from the user node like school, which in turn would have outgoing nodes labeled 'school_friends' and others.

How would I return all nodes starting from the work node and return his work node and all his work friends and work locations?

What I have been trying.

```
Match(a:User),(b:Work) WHERE a.UserId = 'xxxx' AND b.Work = 'JobA' Return *
```

but this ends up only returning the two matched nodes where I want it to return all nodes from the matched work node out.

EDIT 1:
So, I guess writing out the problem on here helped me solve my own problem. I have gotten closer to a solution.

```
Match(a:User),(b:Work)-->(n) Where a.UserId = 
'xxxx' AND  b.Name = 'CompanyA' Return *
```

So adding -->(n) in the match returned everything from (a), where (n) is all nodes connected out from (b), that is it returned:

```
(a)->(b)->(n)
```

this is close to what I am looking for. I really want to return:

```
(b)->(n)
```

and ignore the inbound relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And, I have got my solution. It took me working through this post to solve I guess. I hope it can help out others.

```
Match(a:User),(b:Work)-->(n) Where a.UserId = 
'xxxx' AND  b.Name = 'CompanyA' AND (a)-->(b) Return b, n
```

This returns all nodes list so:

```
(b)->(n)
```

where n is all nodes connected out from b.

Comment: You should use rel-types.

Comment: If you are not interested in `a` at all (you are not returning it) why do you match (find) it in the first place?

Comment: Hi Michael, I am looking to match "a" with "userId" property as all my sub-graphs start with a User node with property userId. Then, once matched I can traverse that users sub-graph.